# How to perform pattern matching with vararg case classes?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have a set of case classes like this

```
abstract class Shape  
case class Rectangle(width: Int, height: Int) extends Shape  
case class Location(x: Int, y: Int, shape: Shape) extends Shape  
case class Circle(radius: Int) extends Shape  
case class Group(shape: Shape*) extends Shape
```

where basically Group is an array of shapes. I need to define a size method for computing sizes 
for rectangle, circle and location its straightforward just return one. But i am having difficulty for Group.

```
object size extends Shape{  
  def size(s: Any) : Int = s match {  
    case Rectangle(x,y) => 1  
    case Group  // how to do it? Also having case Group(shape : Shape*) gives an error  
    case Circle(r) => 1    
    case Location(x,y,shape) => 1   
  }  
}
```

I know for Group i need to use map and fold left, but i really cant create a logic for it.
Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Either of these will work, the second is probably preferred if a little weird at first glance. See 8.1.9 Pattern Sequences from the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf).

```
case g: Group => g.shape.map(size(_)).sum

case Group(ss @ _*) => ss.map(size(_)).sum
```

This is using Scala 2.8. `sum` may not work on older versions.

Comment: This doesn't account for overlaps.  Is that important?

Comment: My assumption is that the question is about pattern matching in Scala rather than geometry.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for vararg pattern matching is somewhat [strange](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2758).

```
def size(s: Shape) : Int = s match{
  case Rectangle(x,y) => 1
  case Circle(r) => 1
  case Location(x,y,shape) => 1
  case Group(shapes @ _*) => (0 /: shapes) { _ + size(_) }
}
```

Note that in the last line, you sum up the sizes of all sub-`shapes` starting with zero using the `/:`-notation for folds.

---

How [folds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) work: Folds accumulate the elements of a sequence using a given function.

So in order to compute the sum of a list, we would write (Haskell-style)

```
fold (\total element -> total + element) 0 list
```

which would combine all elements of the list with the given addition function starting with 0 (and therefore compute the sum).

In Scala, we can write it this way:

```
(0 /: list) { (total, element) => total + element }
```

which can be simplified to

```
(0 /: list) { _ + _ }
```

Comment: This doesn't account for overlaps. Does that matter?

Comment: can you please explain me how the last line works its way too strange?????
 
    case Group(shapes @ _*) => (0 /: shapes) { _ + size(_) }

Comment: @PanCrit: I'm not that fluent in Scala - Could you explain what's meant with *overlap*, please?

Comment: @tom The `@` symbol means "assign to the identifier on my left whatever was matched by the pattern on my right". For example, `r @ Rectangle(x, y)` will assign the whole `Rectangle` to `r`, as well as assigning its decomposition to `x` and `y`. Now, the pattern `_*` just means "any number of whatever".

Comment: @Dario I suppose PanCrit is saying that you can't just add the size of all shapes, because they might be overlapping. The size of the union would, then, be less than the sum of all sizes.

Comment: That's what I meant, Daniel.  Overlap isn't a Scala concept, it's a geometry concept.

Comment: @PanCrit, Daniel: Ah well, okay (thought it refers to some kind of overlapping patterns like they exist in Haskell). A geometric explanation of course makes sence although I don't really get the meaning of `size` here? Should it be an area? Why is it constant `1`? Anyway, just see my answer as a pattern-matching answer with example fold ;)

Comment: I don't think the last line is strange at all, it takes me all of 3 seconds to interpret it: Take all "Group" parameters and fold on element size starting with zero, or more simply put, take the sum of all the parameter sizes.  This is another example of how important it is to understand the language constructs before drawing conclusions on how complex / confusing / unclear a given line of code is.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is figuring out what you mean.  The two most obvious choices are the total area covered by all the shapes, and the minimum rectangle containing them all.  If for circles you return the actual area, they you probably have to go with the actual area.

There's no closed-form way to answer this.  I might consider throwing a thousand random darts at a minimum enclosing rectangle and estimating the area as the percentage of darts that hit an occupied point.  Is an estimate an acceptable response?

Are you guaranteed that all the shapes will be circles and rectangles?  You might be able to cobble together a solution that would work for them.  If Shapes might be extended further, then that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

For Location size should drill down to get size since shape could be group which causes a higher count

case Location(x,y,shape) => size(shape)

That is if size is the number of shapes in the Shape

Answer (score 0):

case g: Group => g.shape.map(size(_)).sum

case Group(ss @ **) => ss.map(size(*)).sum

both of these gives the error value sum is not a member of Seq[Int]
However this oen works
 case Group(shapes @ _*) => (0 /: shapes) { _ + size(_)

Comment: Please do not post questions as answers but edit your question!