# How do I make a class generic for all Numeric Types?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, type-parameter

I am trying to create a Vector class that is generic for all numeric types.
my original attempt was to write a class for all Types like this:

```
class Vector3f(val x:Float, val y:Float, val z:Float)
```

since scala supports the specialised annotation I could use this to generate me these classes for all numeric types

```
class Vector3[A <: What?](val x:A,val y:A, val z:A)
```

but everything I found as a super type for numbers was AnyVal, but AnyVal does not support + - * /. So what is the right way to do this, but without sacrificing the performance of unboxed number types?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436936/scala-compiler-not-recognizing-a-view-bound/4437336#4437336

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't. Not right now. Maybe when, and if, `Numeric` gets specialized.

Say you get the simplest parameterized class possible:

```
class Vector3[@specialized T](val x: T, val y: T, val z: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]) {
    def +(other: Vector3[T]) = new Vector3(num.plus(x, other.x), num.plus(y, other.y), num.plus(z, other.z))
}
```

The method `+` will compile into something roughly like this:

```
override <specialized> def +$mcD$sp(other: Vector3): Vector3 = new Vector3$mcD$sp(
  scala.Double.unbox(
    Vector3$mcD$sp.this.Vector3$$num.plus(
      scala.Double.box(Vector3$mcD$sp.this.x()), 
      scala.Double.box(other.x$mcD$sp()))),
  scala.Double.unbox(
    Vector3$mcD$sp.this.Vector3$$num.plus(
      scala.Double.box(Vector3$mcD$sp.this.y()),
      scala.Double.box(other.y$mcD$sp()))),
  scala.Double.unbox(
    Vector3$mcD$sp.this.Vector3$$num.plus(
      scala.Double.box(Vector3$mcD$sp.this.z()), 
      scala.Double.box(other.z$mcD$sp()))), 
  Vector3$mcD$sp.this.Vector3$$num);
```

That's `scalac -optimize -Xprint:jvm` output. Now there are even subclasses for each specialized type, so that you can initialize a `Vector3` without boxing, but as long as `Numeric` is not specialized, you can't go further.

Well... you can write your own `Numeric` and specialize that, but, at that point, I'm not sure what you are gaining by making the class parameterized in first place.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is: you can't get full performance.  Or at least I haven't found anything that gives full performance.  (And I have tried for a while in *exactly* this use case; I gave up and wrote a code generator instead, especially since you can't handle different vector sizes generically either.)

I'd be delighted to be shown otherwise, but thus far everything I've tried has had a small (30%) to vast (900%) increase in runtime.

---

Edit: here's a test showing what I mean.

```
object Specs {
  def ptime[T](f: => T): T = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime
    val ans = f
    printf("Elapsed: %.3f s\n",(System.nanoTime-t0)*1e-9)
    ans
  }
  def lots[T](n: Int, f: => T): T = if (n>1) { f; lots(n-1,f) } else f

  sealed abstract class SpecNum[@specialized(Int,Double) T] {
    def plus(a: T, b: T): T
  }

  implicit object SpecInt extends SpecNum[Int] {
    def plus(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
  }

  final class Vek[@specialized(Int,Double) T](val x: T, val y: T) {
    def +(v: Vek[T])(implicit ev: SpecNum[T]) = new Vek[T](ev.plus(x,v.x), ev.plus(y,v.y))
  }

  final class Uek[@specialized(Int,Double) T](var x: T, var y: T) {
    def +=(u: Uek[T])(implicit ev: SpecNum[T]) = { x = ev.plus(x,u.x); y = ev.plus(y,u.y); this }
  }

  final class Veq(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    def +(v: Veq) = new Veq(x + v.x, y + v.y)
  }

  final class Ueq(var x: Int, var y: Int) {
    def +=(u: Ueq) = { x += u.x; y += u.y; this }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    for (i <- 1 to 6) {
      ptime(lots(1000000,{val v = new Vek[Int](3,5); var u = new Vek[Int](0,0); var i=0; while (i<100) { u = (u+v); i += 1 }; u}))
      ptime(lots(1000000,{val v = new Veq(3,5); var u = new Veq(0,0); var i=0; while (i<100) { u = (u+v); i += 1 }; u}))
      ptime(lots(1000000,{val v = new Uek[Int](3,5); val u = new Uek[Int](0,0); var i=0; while (i<100) { u += v; i += 1 }; u}))
      ptime(lots(1000000,{val v = new Ueq(3,5); val u = new Ueq(0,0); var i=0; while (i<100) { u += v; i += 1 }; u}))
    }
  }
}
```

and the output:

```
Elapsed: 0.939 s
Elapsed: 0.535 s
Elapsed: 0.077 s
Elapsed: 0.075 s
Elapsed: 0.947 s
Elapsed: 0.352 s
Elapsed: 0.064 s
Elapsed: 0.063 s
Elapsed: 0.804 s
Elapsed: 0.360 s
Elapsed: 0.064 s
Elapsed: 0.062 s
Elapsed: 0.521 s  <- Immutable specialized with custom numeric
Elapsed: 0.364 s  <- Immutable primitive type
Elapsed: 0.065 s  <- Mutable specialized with custom numeric
Elapsed: 0.065 s  <- Mutable primitive type
...
```

Comment: Not in 2.8.1.  Earlier in 2.8 (late 2.8.0 RC, IIRC) there was some problem which I no longer remember that kept performance at somewhat unimpressive levels.  I guess I should try again.

Comment: Just tried again.  It seems okay for mutable operations with the Sun JVM, but once you need to create new objects, there's a ~2x penalty.  (The JRockit JVM shows the same trend but all timings are 2-3x worse, usually, and can only sometimes make the mutable specialized case work.)

Comment: I benchmarked this code on Scala 2.9 and get roughly the same results. Interestingly, the "-optimize" flag makes the first case (Immutable specialized) about twice as slow. Apparently, one should avoid -optimize! Also, the "-server" JVM option helps the first two cases (Immutable) by about 20%.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the @specialized annotations do help. If they are removed, then both the 1st and 3rd cases both become slow, about 1.0s

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to use the typeclass pattern as described here: http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2010/06/implicit-tricks-type-class-pattern.html

Or, you can indirectly use by by using the Numeric trait http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html

Comment: It's a little funny that the blog post linked in this answer was written by the guy who provided a more comprehensive but lower scored answer to this same question. :)

Comment: Yes I also noticed the `dcsobral` in the blog link and had already seen Daniel's answer above.