# Constraining types in Scala's generics to accept any kind of Int

Tags: scala

I want to write a function vaguely like:

```
def doubleit[A](a: A): A = {a + a}
```

But I want 'A' to mean any kind of Int, but not anything. Is there a way to give Scala a clue about what I want 'A' to mean?

```
def doubleit[A <: Int](a: A): A = {a + a}
```

is rejected by the compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a class generic for all Numeric Types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753629/how-do-i-make-a-class-generic-for-all-numeric-types)

Comment: relevant blog: http://typelevel.org/blog/2013/07/07/generic-numeric-programming.html

Comment: question has been edited. thanks for the suggestions. The numeric aspect is really a red-herring, I wanted to learn how to constrain generics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In plain Scala you can use type class `Integral`:

```
scala> def doubleit[A : Integral](a: A): A = implicitly[Integral[A]].plus(a, a)
doubleit: [A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: Integral[A])A

scala> doubleit(2)
res0: Int = 4

scala> doubleit(BigInt(4))
res1: scala.math.BigInt = 8
```

Another possible syntax:

```
def doubleit[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Integral[A]): A = ev.plus(a, a)
```

`ev` is a commonly used name for those implicit parameters.

It is also possible to use normal operations like `+`, `-`, etc. instead of `plus` and `minus`:

```
def doubleit[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Integral[A]): A = {
  import ev._
  a + a
}
```

Or as per suggestion by @KChaloux, import from `Integral.Implicits` beforehand:

```
import Integral.Implicits._
def doubleit[A : Integral](a: A): A = a + a
```

If you want the function to support not only integers, but also `Double`s, `BigDecimal`s, etc. you can use `Numeric` instead of `Integral`:

```
import Numeric.Implcits._
def doubleit[A : Numeric](a: A): A = a + a
```

**Explanation**:

Writing `[A : Integral]` makes the function receive an implicit parameter of type `Integral[A]`. The implicits for all basic integral types are already defined in Scala, so you can use it with `Int` or `BigInt` straightaway. It is also possible to define new `Integral` types by defining a new implicit variable of type `Integral[NewIntegralType]` and implementing all the necessary methods.

The call to `implicitly[Integral[A]]` returns this implicit instance of `Integral[A]` which has method `plus` for addition, and other methods for performing other operations on integrals.

Comment: It's also possible to `import Integral.Implicits._` and then just define your function as `doubleit[A : Integral](a: A) = a + a`.