# Scala reverse string

Tags: scala

I'm a newbie to scala, I'm just writing a simple function to reverse a given string:

```
def reverse(s: String) : String
  for(i <- s.length - 1 to 0) yield s(i)
```

the yield gives back a scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char], and can not convert it to a String. (or is it something else?)

how do i write this function ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Note that there is already defined function:

```
scala> val x = "scala is awesome"
x: java.lang.String = scala is awesome

scala> x.reverse
res1: String = emosewa si alacs
```

But if you want to do that by yourself:

```
def reverse(s: String) : String =
(for(i <- s.length - 1 to 0 by -1) yield s(i)).mkString
```

or (sometimes it is better to use `until`, but probably not in that case)

```
def reverse(s: String) : String =
(for(i <- s.length until 0 by -1) yield s(i-1)).mkString
```

Also, note that if you use reversed counting (from bigger one to less one value) you should specify negative step or you will get an empty set:

```
scala> for(i <- x.length until 0) yield i
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector()

scala> for(i <- x.length until 0 by -1) yield i
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: thanks om-nom-nom, i want to implement it myself so i can learn :)

Answer (score 12):

Here's a short version

```
def reverse(s: String) = ("" /: s)((a, x) => x + a)
```

---

**edit**
: or even shorter, we have the fantastically cryptic

```
def reverse(s: String) = ("" /: s)(_.+:(_))
```

but I wouldn't really recommend this...

Comment: Hi Luigi, can you give a short explanation for your code? thanks

Comment: Wish I had thought of this one. @Dzhu it's just using a `foldLeft` (`/:` is just a short-hand name for that method) which takes an initial value and then applies an operator to each value of a sequence from left to right. In this case, the sequence is the string and the operator is just prepending the characters of the string to the result.

Comment: @Dzhu `"" /: s` is a method call in infix notation. The call is on `s` with argument `""` since the method `/:` ends in `:`. If you look up String in the Scala docs you won't find it since it's just the Java class, but you will find `StringOps` to which Strings are implicitly converted, and here you'll find the `/:` method. It is curried and takes a second argument, which is (here) an anonymous function of type `(String, Char) => String`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7339618/770361, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293592/functional-programming-scala-map-and-fold-left/2303291#2303291

Answer (score 9):

You could also write this using a recursive approach (throwing this one in just for fun)

```
def reverse(s: String): String = {
  if (s.isEmpty) ""
  else reverse(s.tail) + s.head
}
```

Comment: This won't be optimized

Answer (score 8):

As indicated by om-nom-nom, pay attention to the `by -1` (otherwise you are not really iterating and your result will be empty). The other trick you can use is  [`collection.breakOut`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout/1716558#1716558).

It can also be provided to the `for` comprehension like this:

```
def reverse(s: String): String  =
  (for(i <- s.length - 1 to 0 by -1) yield s(i))(collection.breakOut)

reverse("foo")
// String = oof
```

The benefit of using `breakOut` is that it will avoid creating a intermediate structure as in the `mkString` solution.

*note: `breakOut` is leveraging `CanBuildFrom` and builders which are part of the foundation of the redesigned collection library introduced in scala 2.8.0*

Answer (score 4):

All the above answers are correct and here's my take:

```
scala> val reverseString = (str: String) => str.foldLeft("")((accumulator, nextChar) => nextChar + accumulator)
reverseString: String => java.lang.String = <function1>

scala> reverseString.apply("qwerty")
res0: java.lang.String = ytrewq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def rev(s: String): String = {
    val str = s.toList
    def f(s: List[Char], acc: List[Char]): List[Char] = s match {
      case Nil => acc
      case x :: xs => f(xs, x :: acc)
    }
    f(str, Nil).mkString
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of reversing a string.

```scala
scala> val sentence = "apple"
sentence: String = apple

scala> sentence.map(x => x.toString).reduce((x, y) => (y + x))
res9: String = elppa
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation using tail recursion, using an inner function taking the first char of the remaining and prepending it to the accumulator.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def reverse(s: String): String = {
  @tailrec
  def revTailRec(remaining: String, acc: String): String = {
    if (remaining.headOption.nonEmpty) revTailRec(remaining.tail, remaining.head + acc)
    else acc
  }
  revTailRec(s, "")
}

reverse("foobar")  // raboof
```