# Why does maxBy return only single item?

Tags: scala, collections

Following up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093490/how-to-find-students-with-the-best-grades-in-a-list) I wonder *why* `maxBy` of `Traversable[T]` returns a single value `T` instead of a sequence of `T` (list or similar). It looks like a pretty common case. For example (from the previous question):

For the list of students with their grades

```
List(Student("Mike", "A"), Student("Pete", "B"), Student("Paul", A))"
```

I want to get

```
List(Student("Mike", "A"), Student("Paul", A))
```

Does anybody know about any standard implementation of `maxBy`, which returns a sequence of found items?

Comment: Wouldn't that be (descending) sorting?

Comment: @delnan No, I need O(N) algorithm.

Comment: Please clarify. I read your current question as asking for a method providing the n largest items from a collection of size m. That's obviously not possible in O(n) and generally pretty much like sorting.

Comment: @delnan I have added an example to the question.

Comment: So you actually want to get all items equal to the largest item? Then just state that unambiguously! Anyway, I think it's not possible in O(N) worst-case (which is often all people care about) as the number of largest items isn't constant.

Comment: @delnan sure it is. See my answer, which traverses the list exactly once. (Assuming of course that the comparison function is *O(1)* time complexity)

Comment: @DanBurton complexity isn't dependent on how many times you traverse the list. It's how the computation scales with list length.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: yes, that's correct. I was implicitly referring to the fact that O(1) work was performed at each step of the traversal in my (Haskell...whoops :P) implementation, hence the total time complexity was O(n), where n is the length of the list.

Comment: Yes, the complexity thing was a brain fart on my side.

Comment: Useful. Would like to see this is the standard library, `maxsBy` perhaps..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no single command.  The shortest I know of--which will group *everything* not just the maximum value as an intermediate--is

```
xs.groupBy(f).maxBy(_._1)._2
```

For greater efficiency, folds are good general-purpose tools for finding sums and maxima and various similar things.  Basically, any time you need to run over your collection while accumulating some answer, use a fold.  In this case,

```
(xs.head /: xs.tail) {
  (biggest, next) => if (f(biggest) < f(next)) next else biggest
}
```

will perform `maxBy(f)` if you don't mind re-evaluating the function twice for each element, while

```
((xs.head, f(xs.head)) /: xs.tail) {
  case (scored, next) =>
    val nextscore = f(next)
    if (scored._2 < nextscore) (next, nextscore)
    else scored
}._1
```

will do it with only one evaluation per element.  If you want to keep a sequence, you can modify this to

```
(Seq(xs.head) /: xs.tail) {
  (bigs, next) =>
    if (f(bigs.head) > f(next)) bigs
    else if (f(bigs.head) < f(next)) Seq(next)
    else bigs :+ next
}
```

to keep the list (the corresponding single-evaluation form is left as an exercise to the reader).

Finally, even the near-maximum efficiency version isn't all *that* hard to manage, if you're willing to use a few mutable variables (hopefully well-hidden in a code block like I have here)

```
val result = {
  var bigs = xs.take(0).toList
  var bestSoFar = f(xs.head)
  xs.foreach{ x =>
    if (bigs.isEmpty) bigs = x :: bigs
    else {
      val fx = f(x)
      if (fx > bestSoFar) {
        bestSoFar = fx
        bigs = List(x)
      }
      else if (fx == bestSoFar) bigs = x :: bigs
    }
  }
  bigs
}
```

(this will return in reverse order, incidentally).

Answer (score 3):

There is no function in the standard libraries that I am aware of.

```
maxBy' :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
maxBy' _ [] = undefined
maxBy' f (x:xs) = foldr step [x] xs
  where step y acc@(z:_) = case f y z of
          GT -> [y]
          EQ -> y:acc
          LT -> acc
```

[edit] Whoops, this is a Scala question :)

Translated to Scala, given a list `xs` and a comparator `compare`:

```
(List(xs.head) /: xs.tail) { (acc, y) =>
  y compare acc.head match {
    case 1  => List(y)
    case 0  => y :: acc
    case -1 => acc
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing a Haskell answer to a Scala question?  There are some important differences in what is available in the library and how easy or hard it is to write a function operating on collections in various different ways and in which operators one uses to do comparisons and so on.

Comment: @RexKerr: whoa I had a brainfart. I saw Traversible and maxBy, and my brain went into Haskell mode. I accessed this from my feed reader, and thought it was a Haskell question for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
case class Student(name: String, grade: String)
val students = List(Student("Mike", "A"), Student("Pete", "B"), Student("Paul", "A"))
```

then this is a pretty simple O(N) solution, which doesn't involve building any intermediate lists:

```
val bestGrade = students.minBy(_.grade).grade
students.filter(_.grade == bestGrade)    //List(Student(Mike,A), Student(Paul,A))
```

We use `minBy` here because of the ordering of Strings.

As a method:

```
def multiMinBy[A,B](xs: Traversable[A])(f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]) = {
  val minVal = f(xs minBy f)
  xs filter (f(_) == minVal)
}

scala> multiMinBy(students)(_.grade)
res26: Traversable[Student] = List(Student(Mike,A), Student(Paul,A))
```

Answer (score 1):

Student and List of Student:

```
class Student (val name: String, val grade: String) {
  override def toString = grade + "::" + name
}
val students = List (new Student ("Mike", "A"), new Student ("Pete", "B"), new Student ("Paul", "A"))
```

Functional, tairecursive solution, parametrized over List of T and a method to compare 2 T's:

```
// ext: extreme, o: other, s:sample(student)
@tailrec
def collectExtreme [T](l: List[T], ext: ((T, T) => Int), carry: List[T]=List.empty) : List[T] =
  l match {
    case Nil => carry
    case s :: xs => carry match {
      case Nil => collectExtreme (xs, ext, List (s))
      case o :: _ => ext (s, o) match {
        case 0 => collectExtreme (xs, ext, s :: carry)
        case -1=> collectExtreme (xs, ext, l)
        case 1 => collectExtreme (xs, ext, carry)
      }
    }
  }
def cmp (s: Student, o: Student): Int = s.grade(0) - o.grade(0) 

collectExtreme (students, cmp)
```

Runs only 1 times over the collection too.