# scala: accumulate a var from collection in a functional manner (that is, no vars)

Tags: scala, collections, loops

this is a newbie question

I have the following code:

```
var total = 0L
docs.foreach(total += _.length)
```

in docs I have a collection of objects with the .length property

I'd like something like:

```
val total = docs.[someScalaMethod](0, (element, acum) => acum + element.length )
```

I mean, a method that iterates each element passing an accumulator variable...

The first zero I pass should be the initial value of the accumulator var..

How can it be achieved?

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293592 helpful also, but given your question you seem to know exactly what you need, so you don't need a tutorial--you just need to know what the method is called.

Comment: I've finnally settled for 
val docsLength = if (docs.length == 0) 0 else docs.map(_.length).sum 
but all answers were really very helpful

Comment: `docs.map(_.length).sum` will do exactly the same thing; the if/else is the default behavior for `sum`.

Comment: yes, I tested it and you are right...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This called a fold.  It's almost exactly what you stated:

```
docs.foldLeft(0)((accum, element) => accum + element.length)
```

for the version that traverses the collection from left to right (usually preferable; right to left is `foldRight`, and 2.9 has a `fold` that can start anywhere, but has limitations on how it can transform the type).

Once you get used to this, there is a short-hand version of fold left, where the accumulator goes on the left (think of it being pushed from left to right through the list), and you use placeholders for the variable names since you only use them once each:  `(0 /: docs)(_ + _.length)`

Comment: fold method does not exists for Array (well, that's the error I get) Had to use foldLeft, and also specify 0L an initial value, like this: docs.foldLeft(0L)( (acum, ele) => acum + ele.length )

Comment: @opensas - You're using an older version of Scala, I guess; `fold` was introduced in 2.9, as I recall.  Before that there were only left and right versions.

Comment: you are right, scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.8.1.final -- Copyright 2002-2010, LAMP/EPFL

Comment: tried with 2.9.1.final, I get the following error: error: value fold is not a member of Array[this.DocumentationFile]
val translatedLength = translated.fold(0L)( (acum, element) => acum + element.length )

Comment: @opensas - My mistake.  I forgot that `fold` can't change the return type in that way.

Answer (score 9):

```
docs map { _.length } reduce { _ + _ }
```

or (the thx goes to Luigi Plinge)

```
docs.map(_.length).sum
```

Comment: Note that this fails if `docs` is empty, but is otherwise a decent strategy.

Comment: with scala 2.9.1, and the first choice, I get the following error: error: value reduce is not a member of Array[Long]
val translatedLength = translated map { _.length } reduce { _ + _ }

Comment: @opensas - I'm pretty sure you have 2.8 again there.  Works fine for me on 2.9.1.

Comment: You are right, rex, I tried it again and it works ok, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Scalaz version:

```
docs.foldMap(_.length)
```

This is equivalent to `docs.map(_.length).sum` but takes only one pass. Also, works with all [monoids](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/on-monoids/).