# Applying logical and to list of boolean values

Tags: scala, boolean, logical-operators, fold

Consider the following list of Boolean values in Scala

```
List(true, false, false, true)
```

How would you using either foldRight or foldLeft emulate the function of performing a logical AND on all of the values within the list?

Comment: Maybe a general tutorial on folds would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293592

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
val l = List(true, false, false, true)
val andAll = l.foldLeft(true)(_ && _)
```

Comment: reduceOption helps deal with the degenerate case (see answer below)

Answer (score 65):

Instead of using `foldLeft/Right`, you can also use `forall(identity)` for the logical AND, or `exists(identity)` for the logical OR.

edit: The benefit of these functions is the early exit. If `forall` hits a `false` or `exists` a `true`, they will immediately return.

Comment: Becareful of the degenerate case. It can be counter-intuitive. Basically, both of the following expressions are `true`: `List.empty[Boolean].forall(identity) == true` and `List.empty[Boolean].exists(identity) == false`.

Comment: True, but you would get the same results for folding with `&&` or `||`.

Comment: These behaviours are perfectly logical. Given a predicate p and an empty set of values S = {}, of course the statement "p(x) for all in x in S" is true,  and likewise "there exists x in S such that p(x)" is false, regardless of the definition of p.

Answer (score 9):

Without initial value as in `foldLeft`,

```
List(true, false, false, true).reduce(_&&_)
```

Yet this works not for `List.empty[Boolean]`.

Answer (score 5):

I like the `forAll` approach best so long as it fits your use case. It exits early which is great. However, if that doesn't fit here's another, only marginally more complex, approach.

With reduceOption you get no early exit, but you can clearly specify the value for the case where the list is empty.

```
val l = List(true, false, false, true)
val andAll = l.reduceOption(_ && _).getOrElse(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP specifically asks for a solution using `foldRight` or `foldLeft`, so the accepted answer is strictly correct. The answer currently with most votes - using `forall` - has better performance due to early exit. Here's another solution - using `contains` - with early exit too and probably more readable.

For the logical AND:

```
!List(true, false, false, true).contains(false)
```

For the logical OR it's even simpler, no negation is needed:

```
List(true, false, false, true).contains(true)
```

A note about the "degenerate" empty list case, with logical AND:

```
!List.empty[Boolean].contains(false)
// Returns true
```

If that doesn't fit your use case, a marginally more complex solution:

```
Some(List.empty[Boolean]).filter(_.nonEmpty).exists(!_.contains(false))
// Returns false
```