# List of aggregation functions in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a list of pre-defined aggregation functions in Spark SQL. I have in mind something analogous to [Presto Aggregate Functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html).

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>'d around a little in the [SQL API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/) to no avail... it's also hard to tell at a glance which functions are for aggregation vs. not. For example, if I didn't know `avg` is an aggregation function I'd be hard pressed to tell it is one (in a way that's actually scalable to the full set of functions):

> `avg` - `avg(expr)` - Returns the mean calculated from values of a group.

If such a list doesn't exist, can someone at least confirm to me that there's no pre-defined function like `any`/`bool_or` or `all`/`bool_and` to determine if any or all of a `boolean` column in a group are `true` (or `false`)?

For now, my workaround is

```
select grp_col, count(if(bool_col, true, NULL)) > 0 any_agg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look at [Spark Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) on `Aggregate functions` section

Comment: link completely broken: i can't see how to easily fix

Comment: the link is correct, there is some redirect issue. You can search for `functions` on the page that is open, or copy and past twice the link that will lead you to correct page.

Comment: 2 yrs later. Link *still* broken

Answer (score 1):

The list of functions is here under `Relational Grouped Dataset` - specifically the API's that return `DataFrame` (*not* `RelationalGroupedDataSet`):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset

[image]

Comment: Seems no boolean aggregate, like  [`bool_or(x)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)... What the best practice to implement it? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22518890/287948)  not works, and convert to List seems ugly ... Need to implement a method like `sql("(select true as x) union (select false as x)").rowsFoldLeft(true)(_ && _)`.

Comment: Well, for boolean there are simple workarounds, using the same dataframe of union,  `sameDataframe.filter("x").first`, but the question is supposing aggregation functions.

Comment: can i upvote my own answer?  I'm coming here 2 yrs later having completely forgotten about the Q&A. Argh the link is broken: the spark maintainers have some work to do.