# How to map a function that adds 5 to its argument?

Tags: clojure, lambda, functional-programming

Please help me get off the ground with Clojure. I've searched and read, but all I see is how to add the number `1` using the function `inc`.

I'm trying to understand the very basics of `map`. All I want to do is to add the value `5` to each element in a collection. I've tried a number of different approaches, but nothing comes close. Here is one pathetic incomplete attempt:

```
(map (+ 5 ???) [0 1 2])
```

This must be childishly simple, but not for a non-functional programmer like me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `map` is the function you want to apply to each element in the input sequence. You could create a function and supply it:

```
(defn plus5 [x] (+ 5 x))
(map plus5 [0 1 2])
```

if you don't want to declare a named function you could create an anonymous one inline e.g.

```
(map (fn [x] (+ 5 x)) [0 1 2])
```

and you can shorten the function definition to:

```
(map #(+ 5 %) [0 1 2])
```

Comment: Thank you. The middle one is what I was aiming for.

Comment: also: `(map (partial + 5) [0 1 2])`

Answer (score 2):

`(+ 5 ???)` is an expression, not a function.

`(defn foo [x] (+ 5 x))` is a named function.

`(fn [x] (+ 5 x))` is an anonymous function.

`#(+ 5 %)` is a faster way of writing an anonymous function.

These lines do what you want:

```
(map foo [0 1 2])
(map (fn [x] (+ 5 x)) [0 1 2])
(map #(+ 5 %) [0 1 2])
```

I find [this site](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/clojure/) helpful sometimes, when looking at a language I've never seen before. If you search for "function," you'll find a whole section on how to define them. There are also six examples in the official Clojure docs for [`map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map). This is for Scala, but [here's another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2303291/2472391) on SO that explains map and reduce (left fold) pretty well.

Comment: Thank you very much for both the solutions and the references!

Answer (score 1):

Use partial application (see [`partial`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial)) to create a function that adds `5` to its argument:

```
(partial + 5)
```

You can try it yourself:

```
user> ((partial + 5) 10)
;; => 15
```

Now map it over your list:

```
user> (map (partial + 5) [0 1 2])
;; => [5 6 7]
```